# jQuery и множественные select

Tags: html, jquery

На странице есть n-ое кол-во:

```
<select id="select">
<option value="1">Значение 1</option>
<option value="2">Значение 2</option>
<option value="3">Значение 3</option>
</select>
```

Нужно получить значение любого `<select>` при его изменении с помощью jQuery:

```
$('#select').change(function()
{
var select_value = $('select#select option:selected').val();
alert(select_value);
});
```

Этот код работает, но значение берет только от первого `<select>`.
Как сделать для всех?
Насколько я понимаю нужно для `<select>` создать уникальные `id`, но как тогда запускать `.change`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не вижу проблемы:

```
$('select').change(function()
{
    var select_value = $(this).val();
    alert(select_value);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, я почему то подумал что так делать нельзя.

Comment: можно выбирать по id - '#***', по классу - '.***', по тегу - 'tag'

Comment: можно выбрать всё *